# C++ memory allocation: 'new' throws bad_alloc?

Tags: c++, memory-management, mingw

In my application I save voxel-data (compressed byte array) and trying to load it back again into memory.

But my application crashes in Windows 7 machine (64 bit ,12 GB) giving  bad_alloc .

This works fine on Linux ,and even runs on some other Windows 7 machine with 4 GB memory.

Compressed bye size is about 200Mb and uncompressed byte size is about 300Mb.(so only 500 MB reserved before this 'new' statement,which leaves almost 8 GB excluding system memory ). I don't run any other major memory allocation steps before this ,so I don't think memory is fragmented.
I use `MinGW GCC` version  4.5.0

Any tips on this ?

thanks in advance.

```
QFile fileVol(strVFile);

//Read VolumeData
fileVol.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QDataStream volstream(&fileVol);
QByteArray volCmprsdByteArray;     //This holds the compressed byte array

//Read some additional information
int nx, ny, nz, bbp;
int voltype;
volstream >> nx;
volstream >> ny;
volstream >> nz;
volstream >> bbp;
volstream >> voltype;
volstream >> volCmprsdByteArray;     //read our compressed voxel-data

//we have original uncompressed pixel data
QByteArray volUncmprsdByeArray = qUncompress(volCmprsdByteArray);

int uncompressedSize = volUncmprsdByeArray.size(); // size of the byte array
qDebug("new char for uncompressed data size %d",uncompressedSize);

unsigned char* volumeData=NULL;

//Trying to allocate new memory 
try {
    // ##### breaks here.   ####
    volumeData =new unsigned char[uncompressedSize];   
 }
catch (std::bad_alloc e)
 {
      cout << "lu_solver() bad_alloc: " << e.what() << endl;
      cout << "Size " << uncompressedSize << endl;
      //return;
}
```

Comment: Are you building this as a 32-bit binary or a 64-bit binary?

Comment: Oh,I use CMake and I havent specified which buildtype.I use LGPL QT libraries which are 32bit.and in the Task Manager , it shows my application as *32 bit.So I guess its 32 bit build.

Comment: You already have uncompressed data, why allocating again? Also, try sleeping in `catch` and check the memory usage raported by windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are building the program as a 32-bit binary on Windows, you only get 2GB of available address space (the upper half is reserved).

When you consider that the address space can be fragmented by lots of different things being allocated (DLLs getting loaded, thread stacks, dynamic allocation), it's likely that you'll end up having large allocations fail very quickly.

You can try giving the linker the `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` flag, which will give you a 3GB address space on correctly configured 32-bit Windows and the full 4GB address space on 64-bit Windows.  Really, though, it's a good idea to find a way to reimplement your program so that you can use several smaller allocations instead of one huge one.

Comment: The only problem is that the 3GB swith won't work on any version of windows.

Comment: @ruslik:  Right.  Hence the "correctly configured 32-bit Windows" (I presume that readers can look up `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` to discover what configuration is required; off the top of my head, I remember that the OS has to be booted with the `/3GB` switch, but I can't remember if other configuration is required).

Comment: thanks for the answer.I am sorry,I come from Java background and this memory things is totally new for me.Is that means 32bit applications can only access 2Gb of memory maximum?

Comment: It's also easy to programatically detect whether the `/3GB` switch is set by using `VirtualAlloc` with `MEM_TOP_DOWN` to determine the top of the address space.

Comment: @umanga:  Every 32-bit program gets a 4GB address space (that's what 32-bit means).  However, the OS needs to reserve some of that address space for system use.  On 32-bit Windows, by default, the whole top half of the address space is reserved, leaving you with 2GB.  On 64-bit Windows, it's the same (remember that the process is still 32-bit even if the OS is 64-bit) unless you set the `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` flag, in which case you get all 4GB of address space.  On Linux, to the best of my knowledge, you get 3GB (though I don't really know; I don't develop for Linux).

Answer (score 1):

For very large allocations you may be running into fragmentation issues: the heap may have, say, 600mb of memory left, but chopped up into 100mb chunks, so that you can't allocate a single 500mb block. Some implementations of `new` (which really calls `malloc()` in most cases)  are not very smart about failing gracefully when this happens.

With such big allocations, you might have more luck using OS-specific functions like [VirtualAlloc()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366781%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#virtual_memory_functions) and [HeapAlloc()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366597%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on Windows.

Comment: thanks for the answer.but my application should be multiplatform.

Answer (score 0):

If your data size is fixed, or has a known ceiling, you can try a static allocation on the stack or in a global variable.