# How to allocate long array of struct?

Tags: c++

I have such struct:

```
struct Heap {
  int size;
  int *heap_array;
};
```

And I need to create an array:

```
Heap *rooms = new Heap[k];
```

k may be even equal 1000000. For k about 1000 it works, with k about 10000 I got:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted
```

Edit:
I forgot to add, I cant use vector, it is task in my school... Only <cstdio> and <math> allowed.

Comment: I don't think the tag C makes much sense here given the `new` keyword in your example code.

Comment: Your struct is small and even 1000000 shouldn't be a problem for a modern computer. Are you allocating additional memory to each of the `heap_array` pointers?

Comment: I don't know if you are using a C64 or what, but on ideone (that is fairly limited on memory) it works: https://ideone.com/eft8M

Comment: To give an idea of the memory you are using, on a "standard" 32 bits platform the sizef(Heap) is 8 and it's perfectly aligned. So 1M Heap is 8MB (plus some bytes). On a 64 bits, sizeof(Heap) is probably 16 (with a hole between the int and the int*), so 1M Heap is 16MB. I hope you see how much small these numbers are.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using 32 or 64 bit?

Depending on this your process can only consume memory up to a maximum size. I am guessing you are on 32 bits. Maybe you don't even have so much memory to begin with.

Also take a look here :

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/bad_alloc/

Answer (score 3):

*Updated*

You should ensure you are not leaking anything and that your heap allocations do not live longer than needed. Attempt to reduce the allocation requirements per `Heap`. As well, if you are allocating that many `Heaps`: Where is the storage for `heap_array`? Are those all also `new[]`ed?

If you exceed the amount of addressable memory for your system, you may need to run your program as a 64 bit executable.

Comment: I suspect `size` will be obsoleted by the vector as well.

Comment: @ChrisLutz yup, i caught that too, and had edited my post while you typed that.

Comment: I forgot to add, I cant use vector, it is task in my school... Only <cstdio> and <math> allowed.

Comment: I can't see any connection between this answer and the problem in the question...

Answer (score 1):

`bad_alloc` basically means that `new` is unable to allocate the requested space. It surprises me that you see it already when attempting to allocate 10 000. How much memory are you using besides that?

You might want to check what your alignment is set to (how you do this is compiler specific) Using a vector shouldn't really help in avoiding the `bad_alloc` exception, especially not if you know from start the number of elements needed.

You might be running your head against the wall here if you are trying to allocate more memory than you have (2 Gb on Win 32 bit), if this is the case try looking at this answer: 
[C++ memory allocation: 'new' throws bad_alloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130175/c-memory-allocation-problem-new-throws-bad-alloc/4130253#4130253)

You can also risk running into fragmentation issues, there might be enough space counting the number of free bytes, but not enough space in a single cluster. The link above brings some suggestions for that as well in the post by the user *Crashworks* he suggests using the (although OS specific) functions `HeapAlloc` and `VirtualAlloc`. But then again this would conflict with your school assignment.

Instead try investigating if you receive the same problem on a different computer.

Perhaps if it is truly necessary to allocate and process enough structs to cause a `bad_alloc` exception you could consider processing only a few at a time, preferrably reusing already allocated structs. This would improve your memory usage numbers, and might even prove to be faster.